# VS2022 IISExpress test yield errors in phantom ts files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, typescript, visual-studio, precompile

I have a very large asp.net legacy project. It had a ts module that threw some strange errors in chrome. I deleted the ts and associate js modules and created a new one with similar functionality. GenieJsFunctions.ts -> GenieFunctions.ts.

Chrome still thought GenieJsFunctions was there and threw the same errors. When I "repaired" VS, this stopped, but my ts files were not compiled into js files.

I even updated to the latest Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild Package.

Where can I look to check why? They have always compiled previously.
Thanks
Abbott

Answer (score 0):

Repairing removed the phantom errors, but ts files still not compiling. I'll post that as a new question.